# Connection between Algebraic structures and Formal Systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, ring-theory, field-theory, formal-systems

I am a college student with very little mathematics background (up to Calculus 152 at Rutgers University), but have become increasingly interested in computing and mathematics in the last year. I am currently reading Godel, Escher, Bach, which offers a lightweight, non-rigorous exposition of topics in logic and number theory. I don't even know if my question makes sense :) so please excuse me if this comes out as gibberish:

What is the relationship between Algebraic structures like Fields and Rings, and Formal systems? I'm pretty sure Peano arithmetic is a formal system, and wonder how fields and rings apply to or within Peano. Are the arithmetic "operations" applied to fields and rings formal systems embedded within the given field or ring?  Or are fields and rings specific kinds of formal systems (i.e. every field is a formal system, but not every formal system is a field)?

Again, this question might be relying on a radically misguided understanding of the terms I am using, so it may not even make sense. If my answer makes no sense, maybe you can lead me to some nice introductory literature. I "kind of" understand what fields and rings are, but I understand much better what a formal system is, and I understand Godel numbering is, if that helps.

Comment: Define "formal system" here please.

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: As best as I can explain it: A formal system contains a finite set of symbols. The system is grounded by an axiom or axiom schemata. There exists a set of inference rules that you can apply to the axiom to form a new "theorem" of the system. A theorem is well-formed if it abides by the grammar of system in question. Apply inference rules to each subsequent theorem to form a new theorem. From wikipedia: "A formal system is said to be recursive (i.e. effective) if the set of axioms and the set of inference rules are decidable sets or semidecidable sets, according to context." I hope this helps.

Comment: Consider the axioms for [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration) : you can write them in first-order logic, getting the f-o theory of fields. Thus, a*field* is an algebraic structure $〈F, +, ·, −, ^{−1}, 0, 1〉$ satisfying the corresponding axioms.